# unable to find compatible version of spree with rails 4.2.5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed spree 3.0.0 for rails 4.2.5.1..can someone suggest which version of spree should I install?spree is not working although it gives bundle updated there are no files in my stylesheets and images etc when i run rails g spree:site it gives me following error
folder.C:\rubyy\rails\myshoppingmall>rails g spree:site
Could not find generator 'spree:site'. Maybe you meant 'spree:dummy', 'spree:install' or 'resource'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.